# terraform get json file path

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm

I'm using terraform to manage ibm cloud resources.  I'm creating apis for api gate way.

However, resource requires a json file and its path. I have to modify json file for all different environments and regions.

```
resource "ibm_api_gateway_endpoint" "endpoint"{
    service_instance_crn = ibm_resource_instance.apigateway.id
   open_api_doc_name    = "${path.module}/${var.environment}-api-definitions.yaml"
}
```

It works this way with a yml (or json) file. If i use jsonencode or tempfile for open_api_doc i got an error that states open_api_doc_name requires a json,yml file.
Is there a way to convert jsonencode to a file path?

Comment: Does the [`local_file` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) solve your problem?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR no because i must  change json file dynamically

Comment: How exactly do you use `tempfile` and `jsonencode`? What is your template?

Comment: Your `local_file` resource could have the contents set to anything that is templated or JSON encoded from a map or list. It doesn't need to be something hard coded like in the current existing answer.

Comment: localfile fixed the issue thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`open_api_doc_name` attribute in `ibm_api_gateway_endpoint` resource doesn't accept file as a string.. It accepts only file path/location
If you want to use jsonencode, may be you can make use of `local_file` resource to create a file and use that file in endpoint resource.. some thing like..

```
resource "local_file" "test" {
    content     = jsonencode({"key"="value"})
    filename = "${path.module}/test.json"
}
resource "ibm_api_gateway_endpoint" "file_endpoint" {
  service_instance_crn = ibm_resource_instance.apigateway.id
  name                 = var.endpoint_name
  managed              = true
  open_api_doc_name    = local_file.test.filename
  type                 = var.action_type
}
```

Comment: localfile fixed the issue thank you. Also,  do  you know is there any way to create cloud function apis through terraform? thanks..